# Service Fabric .Net Core App - not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-1.0

I am creating a new project from Visual Studio 2015, a Service Fabric Application, picking up the one for ASP.NET Core, but it does not work when I trying to start it.

I'm running under admin power on VS, I tried to reset VS and computer, reset Service Fabric local cluster, and it's still the same. Then, It's strange but the template for API is working perfectly for me.

For me, it seems to be a problem building the executable, and then it's complaining that it doesn't found it, I took a look to the bin folder, and it's empty.

I attached a picture to describe the error:

[image]

I'd appreciate whichever advice/comment/tip/attempt to help me, thanks

**EDIT:** Added pic with the template which is causing the problem

[image]

**EDIT:** Added pic off the project.json

[image]

I'm really pissed off with this bug, I change the references to preview 1 to preview 2 and same error, Seriously nobody more has this error? I tried to uninstall and install SF SDK once again, but still the same, I need to fix it, Any ideas??

Comment: Do you have references from your Application2 project to other SF services in the solution?

Comment: Hi @cassandrad I don't, it's just a template that Visual Studio propose you to create a .net Core App on Service Fabric, I am going to attach a picture

Comment: Can you check that you have a reference to the web project. And if there is not such reference, than add it. Just like on the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/fkfHwY7.jpg). Also check that you can successfully build the web app. Try to build it alone and check that exe is in place.

Comment: Ey, I just checked and it was like that, anyway, I tried to delete it and add the reference again to the web project, and still same problem. The build/rebuild process is perfectly fine, no errors at all. Any idea more? strange... @cassandrad

Comment: Do you have the latest VS updates installed?

Comment: I recently installed a new update, all I have is this, but I can't install it for any reason... do you think that could be a solution? @cassandrad i.imgur.com/JFEsIHA.png

Comment: Probably. You need all the templates and required libraries be installed.

Comment: I updated with one more pic, any suggestion? thanks @cassandrad

Answer (score 1):

Compiling against rc2 can cause this issue.

Execute dotnet --version inside project folder to confirm.

Add global json referencing preview2 will get you up and running.

Comment: $ dotnet --version -> 1.0.0-preview2-003121
That's the result. Where is the global.json? I updated some references on the project.json to work as preview 2, but still same error :( @davidcarr

Comment: I updated with one more pic, any suggestion? thanks @davidcarr

Comment: Upgrade your project json to use rtm. Tools should be preview 2. Download Visual Studio Update 3 Preview 2. https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting/blob/master/WebApp/project.json

Comment: That project json is for Webapp so you may want to remove some dependencies.

Comment: The global json doesn't come down with the templates for .net core.

Comment: 1.- I had update3 already, anyway I downloaded again, and I repaired it.
2.- Same with the tools
3.-I copied & pasted the json file, it's not working because a dependency,         "Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-*" couldn't be found it. I deleted it, it's not working. I have all the latest available updates installed on VS.
4.- What more Can I try? :S
Thanks for your help once again. @davidcarr

Comment: Remove that reference it was local project reference in the git repo. You will not need it. Your setup is fine no need to install again ☺